# PHP - Best way to replace array of strings while dealing with conflicting sub-strings?

Tags: php, str-replace

I'm looking for a simple solution that will replace an array of strings with html code surrounding each string and I also want to avoid repeats. For example:

array is `$things=array("apple","apple pie","baked apple");`

To replace is `$toReplace="Henry ate an apple then a whole apple pie and a baked apple, too."`

I want it to be `Henry ate an <i>apple</i> then a whole <i>apple pie</i> and a <i>baked apple</i>, too.`

My code right now is something like:

```
foreach($things as $thing) $output=str_replace($thing,"<i>".$thing."</i>",$toReplace);
```

However, I get unwanted results such as `Henry ate an <i>apple</i> then a whole <i><i>apple</i> pie</i> and a <i>baked <i>apple</i></i>, too.` or `Henry ate an <i>apple</i> then a whole <i>apple</i> pie and a baked <i>apple</i>, too.` depending on which order the $things array is.

The $things array will have different strings in it and may be in different orders so is there a way that I can ensure there won't be any  tags nested within  tags when it's all done processing and that the longer strings take priority over the shorter ones?

The simpler solution, the better.

Comment: You need to change the order in a way that the more specific ones are replaced first. Like this: $things = array("apple pie", "baked apple", "apple");

Comment: Yes but then there are unwanted nested <i> elements.

Comment: @lukas.j That won't help. It will replace `apple pie`, and then replace `apple` within the replacement.

Comment: Convert the list of words to a regular expression like `apple pie|backed apple|apple` then use `preg_replace()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$things = [ 'apple pie', 'baked apple', 'apple' ];
$toReplace = 'Henry ate an apple then a whole apple pie and a baked apple, too.';

echo preg_replace('/' . implode('|', $things) . '/i', '<i>$0</i>', $toReplace);
```

Credits to @Barmar.

Note that it will not work with an order of item like this *$things=array("apple","apple pie","baked apple");*.

Comment: Thanks! What does that "i" do after the "/"?

Comment: It makes the search case-insensitive.